# How do I convert a TTF into individual PNG character images?

Tags: script, fonts, images, png, truetype-fonts

I want to generate a `.PNG` image for every glyph in a `.TTF` font file. How do I do that?

Comment: You mean other than typing one letter in Photoshop, save, next letter, save...?

Comment: In FontForge you can export one glyph as image. But if you want automation then it's more complicated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Python with [FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io), it has a Python 2.7 interpreter.

On Windows: after installing FontForge, locate the "bin" in installation path and add it to the Windows system path, in my case it is:

`c:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds\bin\`

This dir contains `ffpython.exe` so after adding it to PATH you can directly 
run a `.py` script in console.

`> ffpython myscript.py`

To export **all** glyphs you can use this simple script:

```py
import fontforge
F = fontforge.open("perpetua.ttf")
for name in F:
    filename = name + ".png"
    # print name
    F[name].export(filename)
    # F[name].export(filename, 600)     # set height to 600 pixels
```

documentation:
http://fontforge.github.io/python.html#Glyph
http://fontforge.github.io/python.html#Font

Comment: Any ideas in order to select export coulour ?

Comment: In the example, to get a height of 600 pixels, I have to use 599

Answer (score 6):

fontforge has switched to a python scripting language.
Create a file exportGlyphs.py:

```
import os
from fontforge import *

font = open(os.sys.argv[1])
for glyph in font:
    if font[glyph].isWorthOutputting():
        font[glyph].export(font[glyph].glyphname + ".png")
```

Then run fontforge as:

```
fontforge -script exportGlyphs.py YOURFONT.ttf
```

Bingo. A whole bunch of .png files for each glyph.

Answer (score 2):

This may be an old question, but I found the following batch file works with ImageMagick 7:

```
@ECHO OFF
set f=wingding.TTF
set ps=400
set bg=white
set ext=png
set s=600x600
set alpha=A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W Z Y Z
set num=0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
For %%X in (%alpha% %num%) do (
convert -font %f% -pointsize %ps% -size %s% -background %bg% label:%%X 
%%X.%ext%)
pause
exit
```

NOTE: This conversion only works with a limited selection of font characters.  It works well for all capital letters.  Just install ImageMagick and make sure it is in your environment path.  Include "legacy" commands in your installation.

Answer (score 1):

Output *svg* and *png*, the file name contains *Unicode Decimal Code*.

`export-ttf.py`

```
# cmd.exe
# "C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds\bin\ffpython.exe" export-ttf.py
# API: https://fontforge.org/docs/scripting/python/fontforge.html
# Download: https://fontforge.org/en-US/
import fontforge
font = fontforge.open("font.ttf")
for name in font:
    glyph = font[name]
    fullnamesvg = name + " , " + str(glyph.unicode) + " , " + str(glyph.altuni) + ".svg"
    fullnamepng = name + " , " + str(glyph.unicode) + " , " + str(glyph.altuni) + ".png"
    glyph.export(fullnamesvg)
    glyph.export(fullnamepng, 1024)
```

Answer (score 0):

This online app does just that very easily and visual - although is not open source :( it could help to quickly generate transparent glyphs pngs from given ttf to quickly test. and a manifest of all the glyphs dimensions and features: http://kvazars.com/littera/

Comment: Can you please include the summary of that application on your answer? Also see [How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330).

Comment: This service doesn't seem to work (anymore?). The link destination requires Flash.